# Oracle Buildin Datatypes : Number

Tags: oracle

What is the evaluation of a of value 123.89 in decemial storage in Oracle Databa for NUMBER(3) when there is no scale is defined step by step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what Oracle does *step-by-step*, but - in the end, it rounds the value:

```
SQL> create table test (col number(3));

Table created.

SQL> insert into test values (123.89);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into test values (200.13);

1 row created.

SQL> select * from test;

       COL
----------
       124
       200

SQL>
```

---

Why? Because numbers can have precision and scale. `number(3)` means that there's no scale (i.e. is equal to `number(3, 0)`) so - if there's no scale and value you enter exceeds it, then Oracle rounds it.

Read more about [NUMBER datatype](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF0021) in documentation.